# Filtering the dataFrame based on when condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi i am trying to filter the dataframe based on when condition and then apply schema if it matches else leave it as it is.

```
val schema = ArrayType(StructType(StructField("packQty",FloatType,true):: StructField("gtin",StringType,true) :: Nil))


+--------------+---------+-----------+-----+--------------------------------------+
|orderupcnumber|enrichqty|allocoutqty|allocatedqty|gtins                                        
|
+--------------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|5203754   |15.0     |1.0        |5.0         |[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}]|
|5203754   |15.0     |1.0        |2.0         |[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}|
|5243700   |25.0     |1.0        |2.0         |na                                                                      
|
+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

i am tryin to add a column based on schema if the gtins column is not "na" if it is  i am adding 0, but it is throwing the error saying

```
 df.withColumn("jsonData",when($"gtins"=!="na",from_json($"gtins",schema)).otherwise(0))


 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE 
 WHEN contains(`gtins`, 'na') THEN 0 ELSE jsontostructs(`gtins`) END' due to data type 
 mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;


 df.select($"orderupcnumber",$"enrichqty",$"allocoutqty",$"allocatedqty",explode($"jsonData").as("jsonData"))


 +--------------+---------+-----------+-----+--------------+
 |orderupcnumber|enrichqty|allocoutqty|allocatedqty|gtins|JsonData
 +--------------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
 |5203754   |15.0|1.0|5.0|[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276”}]|[120.0, 00052000042276]
 |5203754   |15.0|1.0 |2.0|[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276”}|[120.0,00052000042276]
 |5243700   |25.0 |1.0|2.0  |na  |null
 +--------------+---------+-----------+------------+----+


 df.select($"orderupcnumber",$"enrichqty",$"allocoutqty",$"allocatedqty",$"jsonData.packQty".as("packQty"),$"jsonData.gtin".as("gtin")
```

this select is only selecting data where jsonData is not null

```
+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
 orderupcnumber |enrichqty|allocoutqty|allocatedqty|packQty|gtin  |
 +-----------+------------+----------------+------------+
 5203754|15.0     |1.0        |5.0         |120.0  |00052000042276|
 5203754|15.0     |1.0        |5.0         |144.0  |00052000042283|
 5243700|25.0     |1.0        |5.0         |  | |
 +-----------+------------+----------------+------------+----------
```

how can i include one with null as well.

Comment: can you post sample data ??

Answer (score 1):

`Exception` in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE 
 WHEN contains(`gtins`, 'na') THEN 0 ELSE jsontostructs(`gtins`) END' due to data type 
 mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;

**To Fix above exception**

You have to convert `na` value to `json array` type to match other values.

Please check below code.

```
scala> df.withColumn("gtins",when($"gtins" === "na",to_json(array($"gtins"))).otherwise($"gtins")).withColumn("jsonData",from_json($"gtins",schema)).show(false)
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|gtins                                      |jsonData                 |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}]|[[120.0, 00052000042276]]|
|[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}]|[[120.0, 00052000042276]]|
|["na"]                                     |null                     |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+


scala> df.withColumn("gtins",when($"gtins" === "na",to_json(array($"gtins"))).otherwise($"gtins")).withColumn("jsonData",from_json($"gtins",schema)).select($"gtins",$"jsonData.packQty".as("packQty"),$"jsonData.gtin".as("gtin")).show(false)
+-------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+
|gtins                                      |packQty|gtin            |
+-------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+
|[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}]|[120.0]|[00052000042276]|
|[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}]|[120.0]|[00052000042276]|
|["na"]                                     |null   |null            |
+-------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input data looks something like below where the multiple gtins are in a array of strings, then you can explode it first and then apply the schema and withColumn accordingly:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|orderupcnumber|enrichqty|allocoutqty|allocatedqty|gtins                                                                                 |
+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|5243754       |15.0     |1.0        |5.0         |[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}, {"packQty":250.0,"gtin":"00052000012345"}]|
|5243700       |25.0     |1.0        |2.0         |[na]                                                                                  |
+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then use below::

```
val schema = StructType(StructField("packQty",FloatType,true):: StructField("gtin",StringType,true) :: Nil)

df.withColumn("gtins",explode($"gtins")).withColumn("jsonData",from_json($"gtins",schema)).withColumn("packQty",$"jsonData.packQty").withColumn("gtin",$"jsondata.gtin").show(false)

+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+
|orderupcnumber|enrichqty|allocoutqty|allocatedqty|gtins                                    |jsonData               |packQty|gtin          |
+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+
|5243754       |15.0     |1.0        |5.0         |{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}|[120.0, 00052000042276]|120.0  |00052000042276|
|5243754       |15.0     |1.0        |5.0         |{"packQty":250.0,"gtin":"00052000012345"}|[250.0, 00052000012345]|250.0  |00052000012345|
|5243700       |25.0     |1.0        |2.0         |na                                       |null                   |null   |null          |
+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your when and otherwise clause it it expects same return type as `from_json` which is possible only when you use same the function `from_json` with same schema formatting

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, FloatType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

object ApplySchema {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._

    //Create Dataframe from the List
    val sampleDf = List((5203754,15.0,1.0,5.0,"""[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}]"""),
      (5203754,15.0,1.0,2.0,"""[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"00052000042276"}]""")
      ,(5203754,25.0,1.0,2.0,"na")
    ).toDF("orderupcnumber","enrichqty","allocoutqty","allocatedqty","gtins") // Map the column to data

    //JSON schema
    val schema = ArrayType(StructType(StructField("packQty",FloatType,true)::
      StructField("gtin",StringType,true) :: Nil))

    //Add column JSON parsed column "jsonData"
    sampleDf.withColumn("jsonData",
      when($"gtins"=!="na",from_json($"gtins",schema)) // Check if the value is NA then parse the JSON
      .otherwise(from_json(lit("[]"),schema))) // Else parse an empty JSON array
      .show()
  }

}
```